Windows Server 2019 printer cannot be shared due to remote connections blocked
Yesterday all domain clients lost connectivity to a printer share on  Windows Server 2019.
Printer is used by domain clients via print share, and is available via Active Directory.
After trying many things including updating the driver, I deleted the printer, its driver (V3) and reinstalled the driver.
However, when trying to share the printer in the initial wizard or after, it returns this error:

Printer settings could not be saved
Remote Connections to the Print Spooler are blocked by a policy set on your machine


Workstation printer GPO does not affect the server, confirmed with gpresult.
There are no local print policies applied in the server, even though I also tried enabling "Allow Print Spooler to accept client connections" as a local policy, to no avail.
I don't know what's wrong, and haven't found any relevant info online. Any suggestions?

Creating or modifying the following registry key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers
DWORD value: RegisterSpoolerRemoteRpcEndPoint to 1 and restarting the spooler service resolved the issue.
This value is typically set in response to vulnerability CVE-2021-34527 published in July 2021.
https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-34527
https://krebsonsecurity.com/2021/07/microsoft-issues-emergency-patch-for-windows-flaw/comment-page-1/
https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Printing.2::RegisterSpoolerRemoteRpcEndPoint
